# Linux kernel crash call stack length

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Would anyone be able to tell how I can easily increase the number of call stack functions reported on a Linux Kernel crash?

Currently I see:

```
[<80100ca8>] (free_buffer_head) from [<80100d2c>] (try_to_free_buffers+0x7c/0xbc)
[<80100d2c>] (try_to_free_buffers) from [<800a9358>] (invalidate_inode_page+0x64/0x7c)
[<800a9358>] (invalidate_inode_page) from [<800a9454>] (invalidate_mapping_pages+0xe4/0x168)
[<800a9454>] (invalidate_mapping_pages) from [<80280f68>] (blkdev_ioctl+0x40c/0x910)
[<80280f68>] (blkdev_ioctl) from [<800e78a0>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x3dc/0x59c)
[<800e78a0>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<800e7a94>] (SyS_ioctl+0x34/0x5c)
[<800e7a94>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<8000e460>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
```

But I would really like to see even more output to get to the root of the error.

Many thanks

Comment: Kernel version being used is 3.14.28

Answer (score 2):

I think you already see everything. `SyS_ioctl` is entry function from userspace call and `free_buffer_head` is function where it actually crashed. It will not provide the backtrace from userspace program as, first it can be application specific, secondly it's not relevant to kernel crash.

Comment: I'll start printk'ing/gdb'ing to find out what's being passed in to generate the crash at this point then.